# AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayeritem

In `viewDidAppear` I am registering for observers:

```
[self.avPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
isRate = YES;

[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
isStatus = YES;

[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
isPlayback = YES;
```

In `viewDidDisappear`, I am de-registering very safely (to avoid any exceptions)

```
@try {
    if (isStatus && self.avPlayer && self.avPlayer.currentItem) {
        [self.avPlayer.currentItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
    }
    if (isPlayback && self.avPlayer && self.avPlayer.currentItem) {
        [self.avPlayer.currentItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty"];
    }
    if (isRate && self.avPlayer) {
        [self.avPlayer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate"];
    }
} @catch (NSException *ex) {
    NSLog(@"Exception thrown while removing observer(s) %@", ex);
}
```

Even after taking all the precautions, I get application crash and on new relic I see

> An instance 0x1742046c0 of class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while
>   key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation
>   info:  (  Context: 0x0, Property: 0x174643810>
>    Context:
>   0x0, Property: 0x17465f800> )

Is there anything else I can do to avoid the crash?

What I am doing? I am sliding the video player to move onto another video player. so there are chances that the keys don't get registered in the first place.

Declaration of player item:

```
AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:avAsset];
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

Comment: Have you checked that is it going to If Condition? And on what event it is crashing?

Comment: Hey. thanks for pointing that out. I added logger statements at 1) when viewDidAppear is called 2)  when key is added 3) when viewDidDisappear is called 4) when key is removed. Ideally, 1) 2) 3) 4) should be printed in the given order. whenever the app is crashing - I observe the behavior that 1) 3) 2) is printed. As I am moving back forth in speed, 1) 1) is also printed. O hope you understand the order I wrote

Comment: Could you please try it like: Remove Observer without any condition as you are not adding it conditionally.

Comment: @AsthaGupta  got the solution?